# How to keep a call alive when a caller is on the car?

Tags: sip, asterisk, rtp

I used Asterisk 11 to build a SIP server, and it is working fine on Android phone. However, I can talk about 5 minutes when a caller is on the car that is moving. It doesn't disconnect a call, it just make noisy sound after 5 minutes.

I know that Asterisk has auto-answer function, but it is working when it make a call again. So, my question is..

Question 1 - Is there a way to find out that bad RTP connection on 3G/LTE?

Question 2 - If I can find out it. Is there a way to reconnect voice RTP automatically by sending something to callee?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is  you have different ip in different 3g cells, seams your operator not do seamless routing in 3G.

You can avoid it by using openvpn or other tunnel with reconnect and do voice inside tunnel. But you will lose voice while it do reconnection. Without voice gap - no way, your 3g operator have deal with that.